# MacBook Pro turns on after shutdown and lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, shutdown

Last night I shutdown my macbook pro and closed its lid right away.
This morning I came to my working station and noticed that the screen it is connected to (via docking hub) is on with the login screen. What might be the problem?

The only things that caused this to happen that I can think of are:

- I didn't fully wait for my mac to shutdown before closing its lid.
- 30 seconds before I entered my room there was a power shortage and maybe this "pinged" my mac.
- I updated my mac yesterday night to the last version (11.3 (20E232)) that might have this bug.

What can be the cause of that and how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: MBPs are designed to work while closed, if there's an external monitor connected. Is is possible you selected Restart instead of Shutdown? Which model of MBP is this?

Comment: If the MBP is connected to power and there is a power shortage, then as soon as power comes back the MBP will think it was being unplugged and then replugged. Pluggin in a MacBook triggers it to start.